# CustomAction <action_name> returned actual error code 1603 in installshield

Tags: .net, installshield-2011

I'm using using Basic MSI to install my application.

I'm getting `Error 1001` during installation and roll back action takes place. I've noticed in the installation log that I get this error:

> "CustomAction  returned actual error code 1603. Action ended  InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

Custom Action dll is a .NET Installer Class and the property is set to True.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your installation project includes a component with **.NET Installer Class** set to **Yes**. Using this option is an anti-pattern, as it can result in modal UI even in silent installations, and often tells you only "Error 1001". You can either look for the component with this setting, or take a verbose log and look for information shortly before the first or only *return value 3*.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes,my  project includes a component with .NET Installer Class set to Yes

Answer (score 2):

Error code 1603 is a Windows installer's generic error code when custom action throws any error/exception. Windows installer does not show actual error/exception in installer logs. To verify actual error/exception we have to debug the custom action.

Please verify if custom action is throwing any error/exception.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  Exceptions are logged in the installer logs normally.  Error messages, stack traces etc.

Comment: @Dougc Please check this out 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368542(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yep, but that's error codes from MSIEXEC.  If you throw an exception in a managed CA you will see the exception in the log if you specify the right options (i.e. "/log Install.log" etc).

Comment: You are correct these are windows installer logs.
Windows installers standard practice is to write these error codes in installation logs instead of actual error/exception messages thrown/returned from custom action. Even it mention that this is not actual error message given by CA. Unless CA is also writing in installation logs error/exception messages does not appear in it.

Answer (score 2):

A verified solution:

Error 1001 is due to a .Net framework mismatch. InstallShield uses RegAsm.exe and InstallUtilLib.dll to compile the installer, and these must match your application's target framework, and the target computer must also have it:

[Error 1001 reason and solution discussed here](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q112469)

[image]

Open Installshield IDE -> Go to Tools menu -> Options and check the following settings as shown in the above screenshot:

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was installing an x86 windows service to an x64 machine. I had to change both paths in my options to my local x86 .net installation folder for my executable's target framework. ie.

32-bit location
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

**64-bit location
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**

Comment: The two locations you gave are identical.

Comment: That was my point - I changed them from being different to being identical to solve the problem.